# iOS Tableview Controller Keyboard offset (example project inside)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard, chat

I am currently implementing a chat into my app. It is a very simple tableview showing rows which are the messages. I have a big problem figuring out how to react to different keyboards.

Currently i calculate the height of the keyboard when the keyboard is shown and add it as a offset. I posted questions regarding this topic before, people tend to tell me i should work with the insets, but i can not make it work.

I want the content of the tableview to move like in iMessage or Whatsapp, where the messages move up with the keyboard and go back. It does work for the standard keyboard but once you switch to the emoji one it gets messed up.

I need help to find a solution or maybe show me the correct way to handle keyboards in tableviews.

To safe everyones time i created a dummy project which holds my current status of the chat. I hope someone has achieved this before and could help me out, since i am desperate to find a solution now.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bldknydjfrwknr9/chatOffset.zip?dl=0

Maybe the way with the offsets is wrong and someone can show me a better solution?

Comment: Usually tableview is not the best way to proceed when creating a chat view. In order not to invest a lot of time into trying to figure out the keyboard behaviour, I recommend using a library such [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController). It is easy to implement, have both Objective-C and Swift implementations, and looks like iMessages, which can also be changed.

Comment: But it does not support Swift 3 thats the problem. How should a chatview be build if not for a tableview?

Comment: It is made in Objective-C, yes, but it does support swift 3 [look at this example in swift](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/tree/master/SwiftExample/SwiftExample). I am currently using it 2 apps with swift 3.
regarding your other question, most implementations that I have came across were UICollectionView implementations, even the above example, is infact a CollectionView implementaion

Answer (score 3):

You should implement this code. Note that this is in **Swift 2.3**, but I have implemented this code on **Swift 3** and it worked I just don't have a copy of the **Swift 3** code right now.

```
// Tag your bottom Layout Constraint (probably the one at the bottom of your tableView which connects to the self.view or the one connected to your textField to the self.view)
@IBOutlet var bottomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // this code snippet will observe the showing of keyboard
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    // this code snippet will observe the hiding of keyboard
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHideNotification(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(notification)
}

func keyboardWillHideNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(notification)
}

func updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    // get data from the userInfo
    let animationDuration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue 
    let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let convertedKeyboardEndFrame = view.convertRect(keyboardEndFrame, fromView: view.window)
    let rawAnimationCurve = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).unsignedIntValue << 16
    let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(rawAnimationCurve))

    bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = CGRectGetMaxY(view.bounds) - CGRectGetMinY(convertedKeyboardEndFrame)

    // animate the changes
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, animationCurve], animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // remove the observers so the code won't be called all the time
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Zonily Jame

Here is my conversion of his code to Swift 3.2 in Xcode 9

```
   @IBOutlet weak var bottomLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHideNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // remove the observers so the code won't be called all the time
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(notification:notification)
    }

    func keyboardWillHideNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(notification:notification)
    }


    func updateBottomLayoutConstraintWithNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

        // get data from the userInfo
        let animationDuration = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
        let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let convertedKeyboardEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardEndFrame, from: view.window)
        let rawAnimationCurve = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).uint32Value << 16
        let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(rawAnimationCurve))

        bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = (view.bounds).maxY - (convertedKeyboardEndFrame).minY

        // animate the changes
        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, animationCurve], animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing one issue with [Zonily Jame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928180/zonily-jame)'s and [iCyberPaul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790851/icyberpaul)'s answer. On keyboard dismissal, my table view (embedded in a stack view with a bottom constraint to the safe area bottom) was extending behind the tab bar. This modified version simply sets the bottom constraint constant to 0 on will hide. This version also provides a drop-in handler.

Usage:

1. Declare adoption of `HandlesKeyboard` protocol in a `UIViewController` subclass, e.g., `extension MyViewController: HandlesKeyboard { }`
2. Create `bottomConstraintForKeyboardHandling` `@IBOutlet` for bottom-most view/container.
3. Call `startHandlingKeyboardChanges()` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.
4. Implement `stopHandlingKeyboardChanges()` to remove `self` as an observer and call it in `deinit` or `viewWillDisappear`.

[View/download GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/scotteg/1f1c027a229fca6b723993000f69152c)

````
import UIKit

protocol HandlesKeyboard where Self: UIViewController {

    var bottomConstraintForKeyboardHandling: NSLayoutConstraint! { get }
    func startHandlingKeyboardChanges()
    func stopHandlingKeyboardChanges()
}

extension HandlesKeyboard {

    /// Registers caller to start handling keyboard will show and will hide notifications
    /// - Warning: Caller *must* implement `stopHandlingKeyboardChanges()` to unregister, e.g., in `deinit`
    /// ```
    /// func stopHandlingKeyboardChanges() {
    ///     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    /// }
    ///
    /// deinit {
    ///     stopHandlingKeyboardChanges()
    /// }
    /// ```
    func startHandlingKeyboardChanges() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] in
            self?.updateBottomConstraint(notification: $0)
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] in
            self?.updateBottomConstraint(notification: $0)
        }
    }

    // Intentionally not implemented to ensure caller unregisters
//    func stopHandlingKeyboardChanges() {
//        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
//    }

    func updateBottomConstraint(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let animationDuration = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue,
            let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue,
            let rawAnimationCurve = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.uint32Value
            else { return }

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
            bottomConstraintForKeyboardHandling.constant = 0.0
        } else {
            bottomConstraintForKeyboardHandling.constant = view.bounds.maxY - view.convert(keyboardEndFrame, to: view.window).minY
        }

        let animationCurve = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(rawAnimationCurve << 16))

        UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, animationCurve], animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
````